# Checking selected checkboxes, radios by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I have few selectOneRadio, and i want to check if any of thoose radio groups(in each group must be select 1 radio) is empty i need to know which exactly group is empty. How to check it by jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: I dont know how to create selector to find groups of radios for example. I was trying $(input[type=radio]).each(...) and i was checking is there any checked value, but it dont work for example when there are two SelectOneRadio on one page. This selector should be resistant to amount of groups of radios/checkboxes becasue i want to use it on few pages

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the element or container of the checkboxes group and use the function `find()` to find the checkboxes element, example:

```
$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: what about radios? When i am using primefaces SelectOneMenu or h:SelectOneMenu ?